# Decorator to change the state of an object

Tags: python, class, inheritance, decorator

I want to create a class to inherit elsewhere, and use a decorator to store specific methods in an attribute.

I tried the following decorator

```
def filtermethod(f):
    def wrapped(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.methods.append(f)
        return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped
```

and define the classes with

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.methods = []

    def apply_filter(self, x):
        for fun in self.methods:
            x = fun(x)
        return x

class foo2(foo):
    @filtermethod
    def method1(self, x):
        return [i for i in x if i > 5]

    @filtermethod
    def method2(self, x):
        return [i for i in x if i < 18]
```

and test the class with the following

```
foo2().apply_filter([1, 4, 1, 5, 73, 25, 7, 2, 26, 13, 46, 9])
```

and expect all decorated functions to be applied of the argument but I see

```
[1, 4, 1, 5, 73, 25, 7, 2, 26, 13, 46, 9]
```

instead of

```
[7,13,9]
```

**Basically**, I want to append every function that is decorated with `@filtermethod` to attribute `self.methods`, (to apply serially with `self.apply_filter`) but I simply can't.

Any clues?

Comment: the only time you add a wrapped method to `self.methods` is when you actually call the wrapped method - e.g., `method1` or `method2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filtermethod` itself is called as the class is being created. therefore, you need to do something at the class level.

below, i changed your code to show how this can work. all i'm doing is having the decorator mark the functions it's wrapping with a variable that `__init_subclass__` picks up and adds to `_methods` (as an unbound method).

```
def filtermethod(f):
    f._is_filter_method = True
    return f


class foo:
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        funcs = (getattr(cls, v) for v in dir(cls))
        cls._methods = [f for f in funcs if hasattr(f, '_is_filter_method')]

    def apply_filter(self, x):
        for fun in self._methods:
            x = fun(self, x)
        return x


class foo2(foo):
    @filtermethod
    def method1(self, x):
        return [i for i in x if i > 5]

    @filtermethod
    def method2(self, x):
        return [i for i in x if i < 18]


class foo3(foo2):
    @filtermethod
    def method1(self, x):
        return [i for i in x if i == 4]
```

edit: fixed for overriding

Comment: Thanks. Can I overwrite on `method1` with a new child class `foo3(foo2)` ?

Comment: with a new class `foo3(foo2)` I was not able to overwrite on `method1` properly. Either `method2` became inactive or both methods did not work at all

Comment: @mccandar try it now - fixed it up

Answer (score 1):

If you run your code and have a look into the methods list you will notice it is empty. The decorator will decorate the method on definition and not on instance initialization. One way to see this happening would be by placing some prints within the decorator and run the class definition only.

In order to achieve what you want, one way would be by using a class variable as method registry and change the decorator slightly as:

```
def filtermethod(registry):
    def inner(f):
        registry.append(f)
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapped
    return inner

class foo:
    methods = []

    def apply_filter(self, x):
        for fun in foo.methods:
            x = fun(self, x)
        return x

class foo2(foo):
    @filtermethod(foo.methods)
    def method1(self, x):
        return [i for i in x if i > 5]

    @filtermethod(foo.methods)
    def method2(self, x):
        return [i for i in x if i < 18]
```

Note that `self` is passed as an argument in the `apply_filter` method.

When you run:

```
foo2().apply_filter([1, 4, 1, 5, 73, 25, 7, 2, 26, 13, 46, 9])
```

You will get:

```
[7, 13, 9]
```